# Редуцированные 1-й степени

Tags: фонетика

Подскажите пожалуйста, в слове *"озарение"* в каких слогах встречается редуцированный 1-й степени?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К редуцированным гласным 1-й степени относятся: первый предударный слог, первый неприкрытый слог (т. е. гласный, с которого начинается слово), и рядом стоящие гласные.

А теперь разберемся.

Озар**е**ние. Первый предударный а **(ударение выделено жирным)** - это редуцированный 1-й степени. И гласный, стоящий в начале предложения, - **о.**